# ipad two UITableView with data source linking to each other

Tags: uitableview, multiple-columns

Need to display data from a single datasource into two different tables arranged just like columns. Here if first uitableview loads upto row 10 the next uitableview should start from row 11 and also if first uitableview scrolls the next uitableview should autoscroll the data based on the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Well for loading your tables you can use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and use tags to differentiate tables and for table1 use `[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` and for table2 use `[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+10]`

Now, about scrolling tables together. I've tried several methods but I succeed with this one:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{

    NSArray *tableCells = [table1 visibleCells];

    if ([tableCells count] > 0) 
     {
        NSIndexPath *index = [table1 indexPathForCell:[tableCells objectAtIndex:0]];
        [table2 scrollToRowAtIndexPath:index atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
     }
}
```

But here what will happen is when you're done scrolling one table, your second table will start scrolling. If you need simultaneous scrolling, I tried `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method but it wasn't working smoothly as required. If this solution helps you, I'll be glad but if you find a better solution do let me know as well.

Comment: this is really useful if the array is single dimension, what if it is multi dimension

Comment: this works fine for plain tables, what if i have sections and rows?

Comment: By Multi-dimensional array you mean your array contains NSArray or NSDictionary as its objects, because Objective C doesn't have same concept of Multi-dimensional array as we had in C and C++.

Comment: sorry for wrong comment, my actual meaning is reflected in my second comment, where my tables are divided into sections and rows

Comment: then it might change a lot of things. But if you just have one row in every section and you're just using different sections for GUI purpose then it won't change anything. But if you have variable number of rows in your every section then you'll have to divide the tables as per the array you're having. But it will become difficult for sure.